# Teradata 3706 error: OTRANSLATE

Tags: teradata, udf

I am using Teradata SQLA 14.01 and want to use the OTRANSLATE function, but it is not working. I have checked the DBC.FunctionsV table to ensure that the function is defined in the system, which it is. However, even when I use the sample code;

```
    SELECT OTRANSLATE('TD13.0 is the current database version','3', '4');
```

I am faced with a 3706 error:

> Syntax error: expected something between '(' and the string 'T'
>   keyword.

All help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This should work as-is. Check DBC.FunctionsV if there's another function with the same name in your current database or syslib.

Comment: Thanks Dieter, 

The function name belongs in the systec database.. Should it be in the syslib database for it to work? Please forgive my ignorance if this is a stupid question!

Comment: I believe that all the system functions should be in `TD_SYSFNLIB`.  Try running it fully qualified:`SELECT td_sysfnlib.OTRANSLATE ('TD13.0 is the current database version',      '3', '4');`.

Comment: Well, there you go then.  As @dnoeth suggested, you must have a UDF in your `SYSTEC` database named `OTRANSLATE`.  Which is a terrible idea...  You can either get rid of/rename the UDF, or fully qualify every single call to the original.

Comment: Systec is not a Teradata defined database, oTranslate should be in td_sysfnlib. Check your Teradata version: `SEL * FROM DBC.DbcInfoV` should return a version >= 14. If it's pre-TD14 it's not built-in and you might have only a version for LATIN data and it fails for UNICODE strings

Comment: @dnoeth thanks for your help! My version of Teradata is 13.1 so you are right about that.. Will this function work if I translate the string from UNICODE into LATIN?

Thanks again!

Comment: Translate should work (OTRANSLATE(TRANSLATE('TD13.0 is the current database version' USING Unicode_to_latin),'3', '4'), but if your column actually holds Unicode data the translate will fail. You better ask TD Customer Service to get a Unicode version of oTranslate.